# Can we please have a sensible date style on the blog?

Tags: feature-request, blog, date-format

[image: Screenshot of date on latest blog post]

Perhaps you haven’t noticed this, but there are only 12 months in a year, not 24.

**The date style used on the sites themselves (Sep 13) seems to suit everyone, so why not go with that?** Personally, I’d prefer the date before the month name, rather than after, as this better suits the way I speak dates: I say *the third of October* or *the twenty-fourth of the fourth*, not *March fifth*. However, the way dates are written here is, at least, not confusing.

> The problem with dates is that they have written representations, and they are also spoken, but the two aren’t necessarily intertwined. In other words, when saying a date aloud, I don’t generally *read* it, I simply *say* it.
>
> [J.R.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/81549/1696), English Language & 
>   Usage.

Comment: It's in American format - MM-DD-YY

Comment: Yeah @ChrisF. Otherwise known as "Huh? WTF? Oh. Oh, it's American. Sigh." US style trips me up for about 30 seconds every time I see it.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Let's say that X% of the active users of the blogs are from the US and prefer the current format.  What percentage of X to you propose is low enough that we should use someone else's preference?

Comment: @AdamDavis. I dunno. But nor have I seen any evidence that Americans are dissatisfied with the date style used on the sites themselves. Have you?

Comment: It's also an issue of the reverse confusion, with the same statement: "There are only 12 months in a year, not 24! See: 24-04-14". So it's a matter of which way confuses fewer people. Though I'd prefer what Adam says in his answer.

Comment: @ChrisF I think the point of the question is that blogs' formats aren't the same as the Q&A sites' formats (Apr 24). Whether m/d or d/m is *more useful* isn't the discussion.

Comment: @Ray my comment was made on the initial version of the question. That just made reference to there not being 24 months in a year.

Comment: **Has nobody *ever* heard of ISO 8601?!!**

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is what I use myself, @michaelb958, and I suspect no one is actually *confused* by it, but some people don't find it friendly. (SE sites are not just for programmers these days.) I'd be happy with that, but my actual proposal is to match the blogs to the sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently the blog was redesigned, and the date format is now similar to the one used right there (or on any SE sites).

> [image]

So currently it seems that the date is quite clear.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a big fan of `d-mmm-yyyy`, so that one would be `24-Apr-2014`. Unambiguous in English, regardless of the local customs.  Would need to adjust the `mmm` bit for other language sites.

Comment: This request just applies to blogs, so localization isn't an issue (yet).

Comment: This is good because it's entirely unambiguous, and it's more immediately familiar to people who are used to the American formatting. (I would personally prefer ISO formatting, yyyy-mm-dd, but I'm sure there are people who find it every bit as confusing as TRiG does American formatting.)

Comment: @JonathanGarber: ISO format is never ambiguous. It may be *unfamiliar* the first few times someone sees it, but that's not nearly as bad, since that way the confusion rapidly reduces rather than remaining constant.